# Flask-sqlalchemy: moving models causes InvalidRequestError - already attached to session

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Moving my models to their own module causes an InvalidRequestError.. This seems to be related to the database session and the way I import db in my models module.

I tried to reduce this problem to the minimal amount of code necessary. First, a working Flask app:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somesecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'app.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, user, text):
        self.user = user
        self.text = text


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    things = db.relationship('Thing', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        text = request.form['txt']

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        thing = Thing(user, text)

        db.session.add(thing)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')

def initdb():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User('test'))
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The index template, again minimal:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" name="username"></input>
          <input type="text" name="txt"></input>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <form>
  </body>
</html>
```

We can make a database with app.initdb(), then start the app and enter some data in the form (username should be 'test'). A new item gets inserted into the Thing table. Nice :)

But then I move the models into models.py:

```
from app import db

class Thing(db.Model):
    ...

class User(db.Model):
    ...
```

And the new app.py looks like:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somesecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'app.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#This line changes
import models


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        text = request.form['txt']

        # these 2 lines change: using models now
        user = models.User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        thing = models.Thing(user, text)

        db.session.add(thing)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')

def initdb():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User('test'))
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Posting the form now gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
InvalidRequestError: Object '<Thing at 0x11111b950>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
```

When I debug this, the interesting thing is that the User is attached to a different session than the one I am trying to add to. So apparently the db import causes something to go wrong with the database session for the model classes? Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

By the way, I can fix this by changing **init** for the Thing class and assign user_id instead of user. That way the Thing instance doesn't copy the session from the User instance. But that doesn't explain why the User instance has an incorrect session to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unwittingly imported your `app.py` module twice.  Here's what happens:

- you type `$ python path/to/app.py`
- the interpreter creates a module named `__main__`, and executes `app.py` in it.
- you import `models`, whicn in turn imports `app`.
- there is no module named `app`, the interpreter creates a module named `app` and executes `app.py` in it a *second time*
- your `models.py` is using `app.db`, but the actual, running flask instance is actually using `__main__.db`.

the best way to fix it is to add a third module, so that it can be called main, say `main_app.py`, containing only:

```
import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.app.run(debug=True)
```

and get rid of the corresponding if main clause in app.py.  then run your app with `$ python path/to/main_app.py` instead.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. I decided to break up the whole application into multiple files, as in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/